# Sharepoint App/Add-in Master Page Cannot Load Error -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: error, app

When i'm deploying my sharepoint app ,the master page is not loading .

Error Screenshot -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of analysing ,got the solution .
Just change the target site URL to your Sharepoint Root site URL in visual studio .As i was targeting the another site collection .

[image]

App will get deployed without any error .

[image]